# Logout button doesn't respond when clicked in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logout

I've made a simple logout button/function that I'm almost certain that should work but it doesn't and there isn't any error either. Here's my code:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { CredentialsContext } from '../App';
import Todos from '../Components/Todos';

export default function Welcome() {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useContext(CredentialsContext)
  const logout = () => {
    setCredentials(null);
  }
  return (
    <div>
        {credentials && <button onChange={logout}>Logout</button>}
        <h1>Welcome {credentials && credentials.username}</h1>
        {!credentials &&<Link to="/register">Register</Link>}
        <br/>
        {!credentials &&<Link to="/login">Login</Link>}
        {credentials && <Todos/>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any chance my backend might have something to do with it?

Comment: could you explain more how it works now and provide more code for context you defined?

Comment: I believe the "onChange" attribute should be replaced with "onClick", for the the logout function has to execute when the button is clicked.

Comment: use `onClick` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `onClick` event, not `onChange`.

Good luck!

Comment: Worked! Thanks, I totally went blind on that

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onChange={logout}>Logout</button>
```

Why you are using onChange event in button?

```
<button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
```

Use onClick event instead of onChange event.

Comment: I must be blind! I'd looked at the code +20 times and never realised that I used onChange. It works now

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
{credentials && <button onChange={()=>{logout}}>Logout</button>}
```

or `{credentials && <button onClick={()=>{logout}}>Logout</button>}`